# shell script runs manually, but fails on crontab

Tags: shell, sed

I have written a shell script to copy a file from a remote server and convert the same file to another format. After conversion, i will edit the file using sed command .The script runs successfully when executed manually but fails when executed through crontab.

Crontab entry is:
*/1 * * * * /script/testshell.sh

Below is the shell script code:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 file="/script/test_data.csv" if [ -f "$file" ] then
         echo " file is present in the local machine  " else
         echo " file is not present in the local machine "
         echo " checking the file is present in  the remote server  "

         ssh user@IP 'if [ -f /$path ]; then echo File found ; else echo File not found; fi' fi

 if [ -f "$file"] then
         rm -f test_data.csv fi

 scp -i /server.pem  user@IP:/$path


 file="/script/test_data.csv" if [ -f "$file" ] then
         echo "$file found." else
         echo "$file not found." fi

 if [ -f "$file" ] then echo " converting csv to json format ....." fi

 ./csvjson.sh input.csv  output.json


 sed  -e '/^$/d'  -e  's/.*/&,/; 1 i\[' ./output.json |  sed ' $ a \]'
 hello.json
```

After running the script manually, it works perfectly. But not working for crontab.

Comment: Try to use absolute path everywhere

Comment: Thanks. Now its working.I gave absolute path everywhere.

Comment: That's a terrible idea, just set your PATH correctly at the start of the script.

Answer (score 0):

What doesn't work from cron, whats the output are there any errors from cron?

A few things to try:

cron doesn't run your profile by default so if your script needs anything set from it include it in the crontab command e.g.

". ./.bash_profile;/script/testshell.sh"

I can't see $path set anywhere, although its used to test for a file existing, are you setting that manually somewhere so won't be set from cron?.

Some of your scripts and files are specified as being in current dir (./), from cron that will be your home folder, is that right or do you need to Change directory in the script or use a path for them?

Hope that helps

Comment: Now the cronjob is working perfectly. I gave absolute path everywhere.